# Executing Spring Cloud application in Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, spring-cloud, hystrix

We are trying to deploy a Spring Cloud (Boot + Netflix API wrappers) based project in Google AppEngine. We want to use spring-cloud-starter-zuul as an API Gateway.

For reasons beyond the development team, we have to deploy this in the AppEngine Standard Environment (Java7, Servlet 2.5). We can't use the newer AppEngine Flexible Environment (container based, Java 8).

We have created a sample Gradle+AppEngine project based on these [guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/gradle).

Sample project code is on [Github](https://github.com/sammysmit/eop-trial).

We see this stacktrace when running the command *./gradlew appengineRun*:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:198) ~[appengine-local-runtime.jar:na]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.util.PlatformSpecific.getAppEngineThreadFactory(PlatformSpecific.java:64) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.metrics.eventstream.HystrixMetricsPoller.<init>(HystrixMetricsPoller.java:86) ~[hystrix-metrics-event-stream-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration$HystrixMetricsPollerConfiguration.start(HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration.java:135) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
```

What are we missing to be getting this error during application startup?

Is this related to Hystrix code trying to ascertain if it is running in an AppEngine environment? Ref: Netflix Hystrix Pull Request 1066 (due to few reputation points on SO, I can't post more than two links).

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it's related to the Hystrix change as that change doesn't change the classpath. I don't know what jar the `ThreadManager` lives in to verify that it is in your classpath.

Comment: @spencergibb Thank you. The `ThreadManager` is in the `com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk` dependency. Even with this added, I had other issues.

Comment: I tried to deploy in Google AppEngine using `./gradlew appengineDeploy`. Here I see an error where Spring Cloud Commons is trying to call `InetUtils.findFirstNonLoopbackHostInfo()`. This results in an NPE, maybe due to AppEngine restrictions with network interfaces during a call to `HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor`. Does anyone have a working example of Spring Cloud in AppEngine Standard Environment?

Comment: Stacktrace for the above mentioned NPE: `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.springframework.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils.findFirstNonLoopbackAddress(InetUtils.java:84)
 at org.springframework.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils.findFirstNonLoopbackHostInfo(InetUtils.java:69)
 at org.springframework.cloud.client.HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.getFirstNonLoopbackHostInfo(HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:49)
 at org.springframework.cloud.client.HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:34)`